# Dispatch with multiple parameters and create action with Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm fairly new to Redux (and especially Redux Toolkit) and cannot wrap my head around the following issue.

I'm rewriting old code with Toolkit.

I understand that I can do the following in my createSlice.

```
  reducers: {
    changeDay: (state, action) => {
      state.day = action.payload;
    }
}
```

and dispatch like this:

```
  store.dispatch(changeDay(true));
```

Many scenarios in my application however take in second arguments, given the example from old redux without toolkit

```
case ACTIVITY:
  return {
    activity: action.data.first,
    anotheractivity: action.data.second,
  };
```

The action for this looks as following:

```
function clickedActivity(first = undefined, second = undefined) {
  const data = {
    first,
    second,
  };
  return {
    type: ACTIVITY,
    data,
  };
}
```

In this case, I was able to call dispatch(clickedActivity(first,second)) and would get both values as desired.

I assume that I have been looking for the wrong keywords in the documentation as I could not find a solution for this. Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass an object in action.payload.
So for example,

```
// assume you wanted to pass multiple parameters in reducer function changeDay

store.dispatch(changeDay({ type:ACTIVITY, data,}));


// Now inside the reducer, you can receive it like this

 reducers: {
    changeDay: (state, action) => {
      const {type,data}=action.payload; // You will receive the properties like this

    }
}
```

Comment: Also, for dispatching an action, you can use useDispatch() hook